# How do I change the document root of a Linux Apache server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, documentroot

I'm trying to learn how to configure an Apache HTTP server (with which I have no experience) someone else has setup in a VM running Ubuntu 8.04.

I know the server is running, since I get "`<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>`" when I go to http://1.2.3.4/ (where 1.2.3.4 is the VM's IP number).

I found apache2.conf and httpd.conf (among other files) in /etc/apache2/.  httpd.conf is empty.

I tried adding `DocumentRoot "/home/username/temp"` into /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and put some simple HTML in /home/username/temp/index.html. But when I reload http://1.2.3.4/ there's no change.

Do I need to restart httpd to get it to accept the change to DocumentRoot?

**Update**: I changed "DocumentRoot /var/www/" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to "DocumentRoot /home/username/temp", but the next HTML wasn't served until I ran `sudo service apache2 restart`.  Can I tell Apache to reload the config (instead of restarting)?

**Update #2**: Got this from [Karol Piczak](https://serverfault.com/users/39673/karol-piczak)'s comment on his answer: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should have a file: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` this is where you would modify the default website's document root.

You can also add more sites by putting config snippets in that folder and symlinking them to ../sites-enabled or using a2ensite to enable them.

Comment: after modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` with Document root map to */home/davuz/Code/www*. I miss this error :"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server." I have tried `chmod 775 www` or 777 but it still error 403.

Comment: The file is now called `000-default.conf`

Answer (score 4):

> *Do I need to restart httpd to get it to accept the change to DocumentRoot?*

Yes, or more precisely said - at least reload the config.

And I see *Zypher* was first here while I was writing - you should see some individual config in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Comment: How do I reload the config?

Comment: Try /etc/init.d/apache2 reload